# Is putting "haben"/"hat" like this correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, indirect-speech

> Ich hab mich nur gefragt, warum unser King sich einfach hat festnehmen lassen.

It seems to me like it should either be like:

> Ich hab mich nur gefragt, warum hat unser King sich einfach festnehmen lassen.

or at least:

> Ich hab mich nur gefragt, warum unser King sich einfach festnehmen lassen hat.

Comment: The original quote is correct. That is how the perfect of modal verbs is created. The third one is good too, the second one has turned indirect speech into direct speech.

Comment: Here’s a fourth one: Ich hab mich nur gefragt, warum sich unser King einfach festnehmen hat lassen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is perfectly fine. Let us simplify and look at the 2nd part: The tense is Perfect, which is formed by "haben" (or "sein") plus an infintive:

> Er hat ... lassen.

The 2nd sentence just uses the infintive "lassen". This is not used in any tense. Assuming Present Tense, you'd say:

> Er lässt ...

The 3rd sentence moves "hat" to the end. This is possible in a subordinate clause, so it is fine, too.

There are several variations with differences in emphasis:

- ... warum er sich hat festnehmen lassen.
- ... warum er sich festnehmen lassen hat.
- ... warum er sich hat lassen festnehmen.
- ... warum er sich festnehmen hat lassen.
- ... warum hat er sich festnehmen lassen.
- ... warum hat er sich lassen festnehmen.

Answer (score -1):

Your phrase in the form:
Ich hab mich nur gefragt, warum unser King sich einfach festnehmen lassen hat.
sounds colloquial.
Correct would be:
Ich hab mich gefragt, warum unser König sich einfach festnehmen ließ.

nur = fillword
lassen hat (colloquial) = ließ (good german)

Comment: The question is about word order; the answer about style.